# Create EC2 Instance With Instance Storage

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm looking into removing EBS from my EC2 instances and instead using instance storage (primarily to remove the cost of EBS - my applications can live with ephemeral storage just fine).

Trying to attach instance storage when creating an instance via the management console results in a Javscript error though, and searching for advice online I haven't been able to find anyone online who seems to be doing this - which is leading me to wonder if it's even possible.

Does anyone have experience with this and could lend some advice or pointers?  Thanks.

Comment: Your EC2 instances already have ephemeral storage built in.  Why do you think you need to attach anything?

Comment: I didn't realise that this was the case - I thought it was an either/or thing with EBS and instance storage.  Thanks!

Comment: Even EBS-backed AMI's have ephemeral storage. It is just that the EBS volume is used as root device in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you select an AMI that has Instance Store as its Root Device, by default you would get and EBS as your root volume.

You can set such filter in the AMI selection screen of the launch instance tool in the EC2 Management Console, here: http://grab.by/x3Lm

Comment: I didn't realise this, assumed the AMI's would somehow use whatever storage you had configured, thanks!